# Search for text of register in function

Tags: vim

I am writing a VIM function which should search for the text found in register `a`. In VIM I would start a search with `/` then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> and finish off with `a` then <kbd>Return</kbd>. However this line in the function is not working:

```
execute "/<c-r>a<Return>"
```

It is throwing this error:

```
E486: Pattern not found: <c-r>a<Return>
```

How do I enter the literal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> into the function? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `execute "call search('".@a."')"` instead.

A bit of context for your question would be good, too.